# Cannot change object field in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a weird issue with nodeJS and mongo objects. I want to convert one of the fields in array of objects for each object.
However, there is no field named proper_date at the second output.

```
Conversation.find({})
                .populate('from to', 'username')
                .exec()
                .then(function (conversations) {
                    console.log(conversations);
                    var conversations = _.each(conversations, function (conversation) {
                        var date = moment(conversation.created_at);
                        conversation.proper_date = date.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
                    });
                    console.log(conversations);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `conversations` object returned is a `Mongoose object`, and you cannot add property to that.

You can use `conversations.toObject()` to convert it to `javascript object` or `Conversation.find().lean().exec()` to make Mongoose return a `javascript object` instead of `Mongoose object`.